# How to calculate Resistor value of CC Pins in Type-C PD?

Tags: power-supply

I want Calculation for why are we placing 5.1K Pull-Down resistor on CC lines in Type-C Connector.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about USB type C? If so, you should add that bit of information to your question (at least in the tags).

Answer (score 0):

There is no calculation.

The USB Type-C specifications mandate that for a certain roles of devices there must be a 5.1k resistor and for other types of device roles there must be some other resistance values.

Please see the specification for details.